# Trying to load to a specific slide in jquery slider via url

Tags: jquery, arrays, load, slider

I'm trying to link to a specific slide in a slider from a button located on a separate page, hence anchor links won't work. I thought about employing anchor links within the slider document, located above the slider, but that didn't work.

Ideally, I would like to be able to access the specific slides in a manner like this.

```
http://myslider.com/index.html#1
http://myslider.com/index.html#2
http://myslider.com/index.html#3, etc.
```

I am using the Awkward Showcase slider. Each slide is located in within a div like this:

```
<div class="showcase-slide">
    <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
    <div class="showcase-content">
        <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the example page for the slider: http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/

Basically, I'm looking for a way to load directly to slide 2 or 4, etc. through a specified url.

I know that I need to link to the array, and I think I need to add something to this function... possibly.

```
    var contentArray = [];
    var thumbnailArray = [];
    var content_count = 0;
    showcase.children('.showcase-slide').each(function()
    {
        // Get content
        var object = jQuery(this);
        content_count++;


        if(window.location.hash) {
        // Fragment exists
        var myhash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        $("a[i++'" + myhash + "']").click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On load try to find the navigation element and trigger click.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if(window.location.hash) {
   // Fragment exists
   var myhash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   $("#showcase-navigation-button-"+myhash).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

The example above is just for one showcase.